# Trying to add a static CMS block to each item in cart

Tags: checkout, cms-block

I'm trying to add a static block that will display beneath each item's price on Magento's checkout page. I created a simple CMS block with the following settings in the admin area:

Title: Free Shipping Banner

Identifier: free_shipping_banner

Store View: All store views

Status: Enabled

I then added this line of code to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml within the first :

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('free_shipping_banner')->toHtml(); ?>
```

The code is not in a location where it is effected by any if statements or anything else that I can tell would be a problem. Am I creating and displaying the block correctly with my line of code?

Comment: What happen if you replace that code with `<?php echo 'here - free shipping' ?>`?

Comment: Nothing. Should have checked that first. Looks like I've got some work ahead of me--thanks for the tip!

Comment: I may be putting the code in the wrong phtml file, but I'm having trouble finding the right one. Any help would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: Turn template hints. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are editing the wrong file.

Try

```
<?php echo 'here - free shipping' ?>
```

Turn on template hints to see the correct path see :

[In magento 1.9.0.0 how can I Enable template path Hint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint)